# Twilio/Spoke: Does messaging service automatically share load between numbers in the service?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

The Spoke app calls my Twilio Messaging Service with these parameters:

```
 const messageParams = Object.assign(
  {
    to: message.contact_number,
    body: message.text,
    statusCallback: process.env.TWILIO_STATUS_CALLBACK_URL
  },
  userNumber ? { from: userNumber } : {},
  messagingServiceSid ? { messagingServiceSid } : {},
  twilioValidityPeriod ? { validityPeriod: twilioValidityPeriod } : {},
  parseMessageText(message)
);
```

There is no indication as to which number in the Messaging Service to use. The Messaging Service has two numbers added to it. I tried a sample run and it sent all 6 messages to the first number added to the Messaging Service. Will it ever use the second? How can I change the policy about which number to use, apart from area code matching?

Answer (score 1):

Disable [sticky sender](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services#configurable-messaging-services-features).

> The Sticky Sender feature ensures the same From phone number is selected every time your application sends a message to a particular end-user. This allows your application to consistently send messages to your user from a single, recognizable phone number.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the issue! We ran it with a larger trial set and about 80% of the numbers went via the number we used in 2020 or 2021, and the remaining 20% that went through the new number went to people we didn't contact before. Is there a parameter to make the "stickiness" of the conversation last over a week rather than 2 years? These are back-and-forth conversations but they last a week tops.

Comment: I read that there is a policy change to this effect. But our service is unaffected. "Effective May 1, 2022, Twilio is implementing a data retention policy that automatically deletes stale Sticky Sender mappings that have not been used in over a year. Any Sticky Sender mappings that are actively used will be unaffected."